# Retrieve the first substring with numbers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, pattern-matching, sql-server-2016

I am trying to retrieve the first substring of a column with numbers (with space as delimiter).

Examples are

1. Get "L90H" from "Volvo L90H Pye No2"
2. Get "Vio55-6B" from "Vio55-6B Pipeline Civil"

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Divide and conquer - something a student should be learning. A trivial bit of searching will find a splitter function that preserves order. That seems like the first step - to split your values up. Once you have that, you can filter for rows where the value contains a numeral. Look at the documentation for LIKE to learn the pattern matching abilities.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? It matters because there are functions in newer versions that will be of use to you (e.g. [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016))

Comment: @Isaac, `STRING_SPLIT()` is not preserving the order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `string_split` your values and then select rows with numbers. Something like this.

```
declare @tbl table(id int,detail nvarchar(100))
insert @tbl(id,detail) values
(1,'Volvo L90H Pye No2'),(2,'Vio55-6B Pipeline Civil')

;with cte as (
select id,value,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by id) rn
from @tbl
cross apply string_split(detail,' ')
where value like '%[0-9]%'
)
select * from cte
where rn=1
```

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: This answer works, but the approach is absolutely dangerous. I just added a position-safe approach...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this. using `string_split` function and `patindex`

```
with cte as (
    select 'Volvo L90H Pye No2' as val
    union
    select 'Vio55-6B Pipeline Civil') 
    select max(t.rn), t.value, t.val 
    from
        (select row_number() over(partition by val order by (select null)) rn, t2.value, t1.val
        from cte t1
        cross apply string_split(t1.val, ' ') t2
        where  patindex('%[0-9]%', t2.value) > 0) t
    where t.rn = 1
    group by t.val, t.value
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Same approach as the other `STRING_SPLIT()` answer... This is absolutely dangerous, because `STRING_SPLIT()` might not return the fragments in the expected order. I just added a position-safe answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer uses `STRING_SPLIT()`. That shows, that you are using at least v2016. It is important to know, that `STRING_SPLIT()` is crap (in most cases), because it might not return the fragments in the expected order. The worst thing is: This will work almost ever. It will pass all your internal tests, but some day it will create silly errors after deployment in production.

`STRING_SPLIT()` was introduced with v2016, and so was JSON support. Check the following solution to find a position-safe splitter:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourString VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('Volvo L90H Pye No2'),('Vio55-6B Pipeline Civil');

WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,t.YourString
          ,A.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY A.[key]) AS RowNumber
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["',REPLACE(t.YourString,' ','","'),'"]')) A
    WHERE A.[value] LIKE '%[0-9]%'
)
SELECT ID
      ,YourString
      ,[value] AS FirstFragmentWithNumber
FROM Numbered
WHERE RowNumber=1;
```

The idea in short: We use simple string methods to transform your string into a JSON array.

```
a b c   =>   ["a","b","c"]
```

`OPENSJON` will read this array and return all items in its `value` column, while the `key` column will carry each item's position.
Using `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION BY` will mark each *first* row for each `ID` with `1`. This we can use in the final `WHERE`.